# ValueError: object __array__ method not producing an array

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Trying to run a code from the link below:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-use-the-timeseriesgenerator-for-time-series-forecasting-in-keras/
Getting Error:     ValueError: object **array** method not producing an array

Version of keras: 2.3.0-tf

Kindly help. Thanks!

```py
# univariate one step problem with mlp
from numpy import array
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
# define dataset
series = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
# define generator
n_input = 2
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(series, series, length=n_input, batch_size=8)
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_dim=n_input))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
# fit model
model.fit_generator(generator, steps_per_epoch=1, epochs=200, verbose=0)
# make a one step prediction out of sample
x_input = array([9, 10]).reshape((1, n_input))
yhat = model.predict(x_input, verbose=0)
print(yhat)
```

**Error**:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-8-550aa8802f57> in <module>()
         11 # define model
         12 model = Sequential()
    ---> 13 model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_dim=n_input))
         14 model.add(Dense(1))
         15 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
-----------------
   ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
         94       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
         95   ctx.ensure_initialized()
    ---> 96   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
         97 
         98 

    ValueError: object __array__ method not producing an array
```

Comment: The code works fine. Have tried changing the version of tensorflow?

Comment: Thanks @Yoskutik for your reply! I tried tensorflow 1.8.0 didnt work. Which version you are using?

Comment: I use version: 2.2.0

Comment: I am also using 2.2.0

Comment: Actually, right now I don't have any ideas. Have tried to ran your code in Google Colab? If the error is still being called, the problem is somewhere else in the code

Answer (score 0):

I am able to execute your code both in Jupyter and Google Colab using `TF 2.2.0` and `Keras 2.3.0`.

Please refer complete code and output in below for the benefit of the community.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
print(keras.__version__)
print (tf.__version__)
from numpy import array
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
# define dataset
series = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
# define generator
n_input = 2
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(series, series, length=n_input, batch_size=8)
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_dim=n_input))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
# fit model
model.fit_generator(generator, steps_per_epoch=1, epochs=200, verbose=0)
# make a one step prediction out of sample
x_input = array([9, 10]).reshape((1, n_input))
yhat = model.predict(x_input, verbose=0)
print(yhat)
```

Output:

```
2.3.1
2.2.0
[[11.588003]]
```

If your issue still persist, please let me know i am happy to help you.